# Middleman - Localizing data/yaml files

Tags: middleman

How do I go about localizing data string that come from yaml files stored in the data folder

wondered if there were some techniques I have missed for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way i am aware of, is using symbols (pointing to translation items) within your data:

**/data/product.yml**

```
title: :product_title
```

**/config.rb**

```
set :lang, :de
activate :i18n, :langs => [:de, :en]
```

---

These symbols can be translated as (Middleman) usual ...

**/locales/de.yml**

```
---
de:
  product_title: "Mein deutscher Produktname"
```

**/locales/en.yml**

```
---
en:
  product_title: "My english product title"
```

---

... and used in your templates:

**/source/localizable/i18n.html.erb**

```
<h1><%= I18n.t(data.product.title) %></h1>
```

**`http://0.0.0.0:4567/i18n.html`**

> Mein deutscher Produktname

**`http://0.0.0.0:4567/en/i18n.html`**

> My english product title

Comment: ahh thats the key so data contains even the locale files also. thanks - other ways had described - - content_for :metaSubject do - I18n.t :metaSubjectHome

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.send` method.

In /data/en/production.yml

```
---
title: "My english product title"
```

In /data/ja/production.yml

```
---
title: "私の日本語の商品名"
```

Then in your template...

```
<h1><%= I18n.t(data.send(I18n.locale.to_sym).product.title) %></h1>
```

Comment: You don't need wrap it again with `I18n#t`